# Within <div> scroll to the first occurrence of a given string

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

In my div tag, there are many lines of really long text and the div element is currently scrollable. What I'd like to do is find the first occurrence of a particular string and automatically scroll to the line that contains that string. There is no line breaks or any kind of string delimiters I could use to readily approximate the scroll position.

I suppose I could do something like this:

```
var max_chars_per_line = approximated max # of chars that can fit into one line;
var font_height = approximated font height in px;
var needle = string to look for;
var haystack = content in the <div> tag;
var index = haystack.indexOf(needle);
var num_lines_to_skip = index / max_chars_per_line;
my_div_tag.scrollTo(num_lines_to_skip * font_height);
```

I can't help but wonder if there's a better (javascript/jQuery) solution out there. My own due diligence didn't find any.

Comment: Ha, I know how you can do this but it'll take a little while in jsfiddle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p id="text">Lorem ipsum ... lots of text.... onion</p>
```

jQ:

```
var needle = 'onion';
$('#text').html($('#text').html().replace(needle, '<a id="imhere"></a>'+needle));
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#imhere').offset().top​}, 500);​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/vq7LD/

Answer (score 1):

If its the case that all of your text is in a single div, something like this solution works.

```
var goto = function(str){

    var content = $('#content').html();
    $('#content').html( content.replace(str,'<a name="goto">'+str+'</a>') );
    window.location = '#goto';
}

goto('Whatever your string is here');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NmhHH/

Comment: fiddle link is broken.

Answer (score -1):

couldn't you do something analogous to using the following Java type code:

```
  var lineToTest = getLine(textArray);

  if(lineToTest.contains(testingLine){
   lineIndex = getLineNumber(textArray-1); //since it already accessed the line it'll have to access the next and subtract 1. }
```

Then just use whatever highlighting technique to highlight the line.  You'd have to obviously create your getLine, getLineNumber functions.  Unless there's some cool jQuery functions out there (which is probably the case).

Comment: it's not a java program and they stated there was one string of text so a getLine() function wouldn't help.